# C++: How to execute a file without passing a command to the shell?

Tags: c++

So I found in C++ that I can use the *popen()* method to run a command and open a stream so that I can read from it's input and output. 
This works for what I'm using it for, but it bothers me that it passes a command to the shell in order to do it.

What I want to know is if it is possible to execute an executable file given the file's location. I then need to be able to read the output of the program. Can I do this without passing a command to the shell?

I just had some concerns about compatibility across different shells. If I design my program assuming a BASH environment, could it end up dysfunctional if it is run with the Bourne Shell or CSH, or am I just overthinking this?

Comment: There is no portable way of executing a program other than the fairly useless std::system(). There are lots of OS specific ways of doing this.

Comment: Use one of the `exec` functions. Combine with `fork` if you want the original program to keep executing.

Comment: Thank you Jesper and Douglas. The exec and fork commands were exactly what I was looking for. I'll definitely look into using them and pipes for my application

Answer (score 1):

Executing any program is [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific (almost by definition of OSes). Read the freely downloadable [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) for more.

You could only care about a particular OS such as Linux (or classes of OS). Then I recommend to care about POSIX systems, and use primitives like [posix_spawn](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_spawn.html) or [fork](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) followed by some [exec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html) etc. [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) gives good explanation and is freely downloadable.

Or you could use some framework library like [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.io/) etc... Both provide abstractions to run programs in some OS "neutral" way (for the few common OSes -Linux, Windows, MacOSX- they support).

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question nicely.